# Remove duplicate and save other data

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview

I parsed JSON. In JSON I have 1000 records containing "ID, Name, Address". The Names are repeated. With this code I removed duplicate Names. This Names I show in UITableView. When I click on Name which is duplicated I need to show his addresses and ID. I wonder how to save related address and ID.

```
JSON file:

    {
    "ID":123, 
    "Name":"Alex", 
    "Address":"padd str. 125"
    },
    {
    "ID":333, 
    "Name":"Alex", 
    "Address":"padd str. 33"
    },
    {
    "ID":232, 
    "Name":"Alexander", 
    "Address":"padd str. 22"
    },

-(void)updateUIWithDictionary1:(NSDictionary*)json {

    Address = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    id item = [json valueForKeyPath:@"Address"];
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

        [Address addObjectsFromArray:item];
    }
    Name = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    id item1 = [json valueForKeyPath:@"Name"];
    if ([item1 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

        for(id e in item1)
        {
            if(![Name containsObject:e])
            {
                [Name addObject:e];
            }
        }
    }
    ID = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    id item2 = [json valueForKeyPath:@"ID"];
    if ([item2 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

        [ID addObjectsFromArray:item2];
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the structure of your JSON.
Do you have an array of dictionaries {"ID":123, "name":"Alex", "address":"padd str. 125"} or a dictionary of arrays {"Name":["alex", "sam", ...]}?

Comment: look with same "name" u have different address i.e they are two different identities what is the need to eliminate the duplicate names ?

Comment: I have like this {"ID":123, "name":"Alex", "address":"padd str. 125"}